# Accessing collection in multiple views - Backbone + RequireJS

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am working on my first RequireJS/Backbone app and I've hit a wall. There's a lot of code smell here, and I know I'm just missing on the pattern.

I have a route that shows all promotions, and one that shows a specific promotion (by Id):

```
showPromotions: function () {
    var promotionsView = new PromotionsView();
},
editPromotion: function (promotionId) {
    vent.trigger('promotion:show', promotionId);
}
```

In my promotions view initializer, I new up my PromotionsCollection & fetch. I also subscribe to the reset event on the collection. This calls addAll which ultimately builds a ul of all Promotions & appends it to a container div in the DOM.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'app/vent',
  'models/promotion/PromotionModel',
  'views/promotions/Promotion',
  'collections/promotions/PromotionsCollection',
  'text!templates/promotions/promotionsListTemplate.html',
  'views/promotions/Edit'
], function ($, _, Backbone, vent, PromotionModel, PromotionView, PromotionsCollection, promotionsListTemplate, PromotionEditView) {
    var Promotions = Backbone.View.extend({
        //el: ".main",
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new PromotionsCollection();
            this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        render: function () {
            $("#page").html(promotionsListTemplate);
            return this;
        },
        addAll: function () {
            //$("#page").html(promotionsListTemplate);
            this.$el.empty().append('<li class="hide hero-unit NoCampaignsFound"><p>No campaigns found</p></li>');
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            this.render();
            $("div.promotionsList").append(this.$el);
        },

        addOne: function (promotion) {
            var promotionView = new PromotionView({ model: promotion });
            this.$el.append(promotionView.render().el);
        }    
    });
    return Promotions;
});
```

Each promotion in the list has an edit button with a href of `#promotion/edit/{id}`. If I navigate first to the list page, and click edit, it works just fine. However, I cannot  navigate straight to the edit page. I understand this is because I'm populating my collection in the initialize method on my View. I could have a "if collection.length == 0, fetch" type of call, but I prefer a design that doesn't have to perform this kind of check. My questions:

1. How do I make sure my collection is populated regardless of which route I took?
2. I'm calling render inside of my `addAll` method to pull in my template. I could certainly move that code in to `addAll`, but overall this code smells too. Should I have a "parent view" that's responsible for rendering the template itself, and instantiates my list/edit views as needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one take.  Just remember that there is more than one way to do this.  In fact, this may not be the best one, but I do this myself, so maybe someone else can help us both!

First off though, you have a lot of imports in this js file.  It's much easier to manage over time as you add/remove things if you import them like this:

```
define(function( require ){
  // requirejs - too many includes to pass in the array
  var $ = require('jquery'),
      _ = require('underscore'),
      Backbone = require('backbone'),
      Ns = require('namespace'),
      Auth = require('views/auth/Auth'),
      SideNav = require('views/sidenav/SideNav'),
      CustomerModel = require('models/customer/customer');
      // blah blah blah...});
```

That's just a style suggestion though, your call.  As for the collection business, something like this:

```
  Forms.CustomerEdit = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template( CustomerEditTemplate ),

    initialize: function( config ){
      var view = this;
      view.model.on('change',view.render,view);
    },

    deferredRender: function ( ) {
      var view = this;
      // needsRefresh decides if this model needs to be fetched.
      // implement on the model itself when you extend from the backbone
      // base model.
      if ( view.model.needsRefresh() ) {
        view.model.fetch();
      } else {
        view.render();        
      }
    },

    render:function () {
      var view = this;
      view.$el.html( view.template({rows:view.model.toJSON()}) );
      return this;
    }

  });


   CustomerEdit = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",

    attributes: {"id":"customerEdit",
                 "data-role":"page"},

    template: _.template( CustomerEditTemplate, {} ),


    initialize: function( config ){
      var view = this;
      // config._id is passed in from the router, as you have done, aka promotionId
      view._id = config._id;

      // build basic dom structure
      view.$el.append( view.template );

      view._id = config._id;
      // Customer.Foo.Bar would be an initialized collection that this view has
      // access to.  In this case, it might be a global or even a "private" 
      // object that is available in a closure 
      view.model = ( Customer.Foo.Bar ) ? Customer.Foo.Bar.get(view._id) : new CustomerModel({_id:view._id});

      view.subViews = {sidenav:new Views.SideNav({parent:view}),
                       auth:new Views.Auth(),
                       editCustomer: new Forms.CustomerEdit({parent:view,
                                      el:view.$('#editCustomer'),
                                      model:view.model})
                                    };

    },

    render:function () {
      var view = this;
      // render stuff as usual
      view.$('div[data-role="sidetray"]').html( view.subViews.sidenav.render().el );
      view.$('#security').html( view.subViews.auth.render().el );
      // magic here. this subview will return quickly or fetch and return later
      // either way, since you passed it an 'el' during init, it will update the dom
      // independent of this (parent) view render call.
      view.subViews.editCustomer.deferredRender();

      return this;
    }
```

Again, this is just one way and might be terribly wrong, but it's how I do it and it seems to work great.  I usually put a "loading" message in the dom where the subview eventually renders with replacement html.

Comment: Sorry, was in holiday party land this weekend. I'll check this out & take a look today/tomorrow when I get back to that part of the app.

Comment: I just want to confirm something - your needsRefresh() method - is that just a bool that's set based on initial fetch? Or is there something more complicated there? If more complicated, can you edit your example to include that method in the Model? Actually, for others sake as well, I suppose just updating your solution to include a model w/ refresh would be helpful.

Comment: Would still love to know your thoughts on the above question(s)

Comment: sure, no problem.  I've actually abandoned the code above for a more decoupled way using events.  I can try to package that up for you.